# addEventListener "click" can't find name attribute from json file

Tags: javascript

All I want to achieve for now is to add click function to buttons that I've created using a for loop. They've each got their own unique so I know that each button should have a unique console log. Yet when I click on the button this error appears:

[Error Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFfWf.png)

This is the code I've written:

```
function imgMake() {
  fetch("csvjson.json")
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(response => {
        for(var i = 74; i <= 429; i++) {
          var select = document.getElementById(response[i - 74].Name_and_model);

          var el3 = document.createElement("button");
          el3.className = "carinfobtn"
          el3.textContent = "Info →"
          el3.id = response[i - 74].Name_and_model + "2";
          el3.addEventListener("click", function() {console.log(response[i-74].Name_and_model);});
          select.appendChild(el3)
        }
      })
}
```

I'm expecting the code to console log the name yet I'm getting that error. Anyone know what's wrong? (Also ignore the weird numbers with i, I need them in those wierd configuration for other elements)

Comment: Change `var i` to `let i`.

Comment: The issue you're facing is related to JavaScript's closures. The variable i is being captured by the click event listeners, but by the time the event listener is executed, the loop has already finished, and i has its final value. To solve this problem, you can create a function to capture the current value of i at each iteration. You can use an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) to achieve this.